# Функция выбора однотипных элементов формы

Tags: c#

```
 public  void FBD(int I)
            {
                FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                DialogResult result = FBD.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Formas.textBox[I].Text = FBD.SelectedPath;
                    Formas.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Настройка";
                }
            }
```

Как правильно обращаться к i элементам в функции? Выдаёт ошибку

> "Install.Form1" не содержит определение для "textBox". Не удалось
>   найти метод  расширения "textBox", принимающий первый аргумент типа
>   "Install.Form1"  (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)

Comment: А у вас в `Formas` есть поле или свойство `textBox`? Если нет, непонятно, что вас удивляет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private List<TextBox> GetTextBoxesFrom(Control parent) {
    List<TextBox> result = new List<TextBox>();
    List<TextBox> indirectChildren = null;
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        //check for the base case
        if (c is TextBox)
            result.Add((TextBox)c);
        else if (c.HasChildren)    // it's a container
        {
            indirectChildren = GetTextBoxesFrom(c);
            result.AddRange(indirectChildren);
        }
    }
    return result; }

 var textBoxList = GetTextBoxesFrom(this);
 textBoxList[0].Text = "0";
```

Answer (score 2):

Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Используй вот это:

```
foreach(var pb in this.Controls.OfType<Твой тип>())
{
  //do stuff
}
```

---

Если `Formas` в твоем коде- это наследник Form, то к i-ому элементу ты можешь обратиться как-то так:

```
Formas.Controls.OfType<Твой тип>()[i]
```

Comment: Можно пример? У меня не получается

Comment: А что именно не получается? На форму в какой-нибудь метод просто нужно скопировать мой код.

Comment: Покажите пример на моём коде, у меня не получилось  обратиться к i элементу.